# mysql get last 10 records from each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mysql table called `ware_stock_transaction` and it has `order_no`, `order_type`, `created_date`, `item_no`.

I want to get the last 10 record from each item, like this:

```
item A (10 records)
item B (10 records)
item C (10 records)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use variables:

```
select wst.*
from (select wst.*,
             (@rn := if(@i = item_no, @rn + 1,
                        if(@i := item_no, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from ware_stock_transaction wst cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @i := '') params
      order by item_no, created_date desc
     ) wst
where rn <= 10;
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer and quick response . it worked